# Not able to use glew.h on Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, glew

Recently, I moved over to Linux from Windows and was trying to follow a Udemy course, originally taught using Visual Studio on Windows.

I need to use two header files **glfw3.h** and **glew.h** in the course.

I can import **glfw3.h** and use it just fine, but the **glew.h** function is showing some errors.

I used the code **sudo apt-get install libglew-dev** to get the library files. But still error pops up.

**CODE :**

```
    #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
    #include <GL/glew.h>

    int main(void)
    {}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE :**

```
In file included from Lesson01.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:85:2: error: #error gl.h included before glew.h
#error gl.h included before glew.h
^~~~~

In file included from Lesson01.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16088:93: error: conflicting declaration     
‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELFVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLfloat*)’
LAPIENTRY * PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELFVSGIXPROC) (GLenum pname, GLfloat*    
params);
     ^

In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0,
             from /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:171,
             from Lesson01.cpp:1:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:12070:25: note: previous declaration as  
‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELFVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, const     
GLfloat*)’typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELFVSGIXPROC)   
(GLenum pname, const GLfloat *params);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from Lesson01.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:16090:91: error: conflicting declaration 
‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELIVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, GLint*)’
(GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELIVSGIXPROC) (GLenum pname, GLint*  
params);
     ^

In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0,
             from /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:171,
             from Lesson01.cpp:1:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:12072:25: note: previous declaration as   
‘typedef void (* PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELIVSGIXPROC)(GLenum, const 
GLint*)’ typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTMODELIVSGIXPROC) 
(GLenum pname, const GLint *params);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Please do not post images of errors, but copy in text mode. See [ask]

Comment: Also, try to post a [MCVE] to help us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by you compiler, order of included files matters:

```
error: #error gl.h included before glew.h
```

Simply invert the two first lines:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: But could you tell me where I have used "gl.h" as specified by the error message??

Comment: `gl.h` is included by file `glfw3.h`. You can check it with :`grep "gl\.h" /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h`

Comment: @AtishPratapSinghRathour: The recursive includes are also _directly listed_ in the compiler messages posted in the question: `In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0, from /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:171, from Lesson01.cpp:1`. Read those compiler errors, that's what they are there for.